# jQuery - only calling .click() on the foreground element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/8AqgU/

The example in that link shows a nested ordered list. If you open up your Chrome/Firebug console, you can see that clicking a child element causes a .click() event on its parents as well.

Is there a way to just detect the .click() on the visible foreground element that was clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to stop the propogation of the click:

```
$('#toc li').click(function(e) {
    console.log ($(this).attr('id'));
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Check out [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) for more info